# Why doesn't grep work on this file?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to grep [this file](http://sprunge.us/NhHR). Here is a sample of the file (Note: my problem is obviously not present if you just copy/paste this sample and run grep)

```
              'startTime': 1415066802,
              'timeout': 6,
              'totalRequests': 9201823,
              'write': 0}]}
INFO:root:Running setup module stop (cwd=/home/techempower/FrameworkBenchmarks/frameworks/Java)
benchmark:   3% |#                                       | Rough ETA:  17:27:56
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Running Test: activeweb-raw
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO:root:Running setup module start (cwd=/home/techempower/FrameworkBenchmarks/frameworks/Java)
INFO:root:Called setup.py start
INFO:root:Sleeping 60 seconds to ensure framework is ready
```

I'd like to extract lines like these:

`benchmark:   1% |                                        | Rough ETA:  00:00:01`

Here's the output I get when I run grep:

```
$ cat NhHR | grep Rough
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It appears that I'm detecting the text, but the lines that are being returned do not include the detected text (as thought it's not printing in my terminal?). Printing contextual lines doesn't provide any further clues to me

Does anyone know how I can get grep to work for this file, or why it's not working currently?

Comment: Unless you can include the content here, this is likely to be closed. If the link is unavailable for some reason, the question is meaningless and is of no use to future readers.

Comment: content is already in question - I linked to it

Comment: @Hamy If this forum stays for 10 more years, then your link must do so, or this post will be meaning less.  That's why i tell you to copy some of the file into this forum, not using link.

Comment: @Hamy There's a difference between linking to something and actually including it in the question. You should put the smallest amount of code/content required to reproduce your problem directly into the question.

Comment: Guys, this is likely an encoding issue. What's the value of copy/pasting when that will remove the problem?

Comment: EDIT - Added some sample text, but as I said above copy/pasting the text removes the problem

Comment: If the problem can't be presented here, it's not a question that will be useful to others in the future. This is not (and has never been) a "solve my problem for me" site. It's a collection of knowledge that will benefit *many users*, and if it happens to help with your immediate problem that's a great side effect. If the primary content is elsewhere, and that other site disappears/is off line/moves/whatever makes it unavailable, the question has no value.

Comment: Ken, it's silly to think there is no value in the question of `grep output is not showing my results but it is matching` and the answer of `your output may contain a carriage return`--especially as it's now one of the only results for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that the matched line contains a carriage return just before the long dashes that when printed to stdout makes the non-dashed part of the line to be overwritten. Try piping grep to a file and open the file in an editor, you should see the matched part.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it. Piping to `less` does the trick too (went ahead and download the file and tried it)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Also, I never mentally connected that a carriage return quite literally moves the text entry point back to the far left like on an old typewriter. Suddenly CRLF makes a lot more sense :-P